# Shared /boot/efi partition between Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, windows

I have a new laptop with preinstalled Windows 10. I'd like to make it dual-boot with Ubuntu (20.04). To make things simple, I only created 3 mount points `/swap`, `/` and `/home` in the allocated space for the Ubuntu. After finishing the installation, I realised that Ubuntu also mounts the `/boot/efi` in the same boot partition with Windows.

Is it normal? What would be the impacts? Would it recommended to have create a separate partition to mount `/boot`?

Comment: It is normal, there aren't any impacts, you get to dual boot. Also, /boot, and /boot/efi are not the same.

Comment: Do not create /boot. Only a few with server installs may need a /boot partition. You also do not need swap partition as installer uses a swap file, since 17.04. So any instructions you have on adding a swap partition must have been old. But swap partition will be used if found by installer. Again a few with server installs may want a swap partition or somewhat larger swap than default swap file. Or very old system, with limited RAM, less than 4GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally a UEFI system has just one EFI System Partition (ESP), which in Linux usually gets mounted to `/boot/efi`. Confirm that with just `mount` command: `/boot` isn't a separate mount point, but `/boot/efi` is. And since system has just one ESP, that's the same ESP Windows uses. You should have there /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT, /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft, /boot/efi/EFI/Ubuntu, something like this.

As for separate /swap, it does no harm, but *may* make hibernating Linux less painful. Also it is better because it is simpler, swap file is a file and is routed via swap code AND file system code, and busy file system might make it slower. You can avoid this file system code, why not take this shorter path? This is why I only use swap files as last resort and always recommend to use swap only on separate partitions or volumes.

Comment: Yup, the swap partition is meant for the hibernate. I don't think I would need it because of lack of RAM (I'm having 16 Gb).